# como puedo cambiar el valor de un select en react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select

buenos días estoy trabajando con select en react que se llena con datos de una base de datos, lo que quiero es que en base a una condicion que debo realizar dentro de la iteracion se marque como selecionado el valor que cumple la condicion.

```
<IonSelect value={valor} placeholder="Select One" onChange={(e)=>{setvalor(e.target.value)}}>
             
 {loading
                ? "Cargando..."
                : restItem.length === 0
                ? "sin datos"
                : restItem.map((item: any) => (
                    props.rest.idclientes === item.value 
                    ?((e)=>{setvalor(valor nuevo))
                    :<IonSelectOption key={item.value}>
                      {item.name}
                    </IonSelectOption>
                  ))}
            </IonSelect>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenes que marcar como `selected=true` el `IonSelectOption` que cumpla la condicion, ej:

```
<IonSelect value={valor} placeholder="Select One" onChange={(e)=>{setvalor(e.target.value)}}>
             
 {loading
                ? "Cargando..."
                : restItem.length === 0
                ? "sin datos"
                : restItem.map((item: any) => (
                    props.rest.idclientes === item.value 
                    ?((e)=>{setvalor(valor nuevo))
                    :<IonSelectOption key={item.value} selected={(1 == 1)}>// remplaza el 1 == 1 por tu condicion
                      {item.name}
                    </IonSelectOption>
                  ))}
            </IonSelect>
```